# ReactJS: Number in row table

Tags: reactjs

here I want to generate a number in the table. but I'm stuck here, how do I create a number table in reactjs? Thanks.

expectation

[image]

but the result

[image]

My Code:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col" class="p-3">No. </th>
              <th scope="col" class="p-3">Kompetitor</th>
              <th scope="col" class="">Jumlah Witel : 11</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {lists.length > 0 &&
              lists.map((item, index) => (
                <tr key={item.kompetitor}>
                    <td className="pl-3">
                        1. 
                    </td>
                  <td width="20%" className="pl-6">
                    {item.kompetitor === "stroomnet"
                      ? "Icon Net"
                      : item.kompetitor}
                  </td>
                  <td width="80%">
                    <ProgressBar
                      total={
                        lists.map((item) => Number(item.count))
                        // .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0)
                      }
                      status={status}
                      count={Number(item.count) || 0}
                      percent={convertPercent(index)}
                    />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **index** passed on the map method to create the indexed table

Change this line

```
<td className="pl-3">
    1. 
</td>
```

To this

```
<td className="pl-3">
    {index+1}. 
</td>
```